# JQuery for displaying Likert results?

Tags: jquery, css

An application stores results from a form with several Likert scales (1: fair - 5:very good).  The data is already saved, now I need a slick way of displaying it.

Is there a jquery library that converts an array of Likert values into an attractive graphical representation (such as a gradient, or bar)?  I already have the backend form created, this is for the public facing side where no data input is done.  I'm only showing the results.

I could put together something from scratch but don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a D3.js based solutions which may suite your needs: https://github.com/phil303/Likert-Or-Leave-it